# When trying to publish the extension, receive error: Part URI is not valid per rules defined in the Open Packaging Conventions specification

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, azure-devops

I'm trying to publish an extension by vsce, I logged in with the user access token,
after the build its create a file named 'NadavShaked.my-first-extension v1.0.968.vsix'
I'm trying to publish the extension to the marketplace by this command 'vsce publish' and received this error:
[image]

this is the guide I used
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension

this is my azure-devops-extension.json file:

```json
{
  "manifestVersion": 1,
  "id": "my-first-extension",
  "publisher": "NadavShaked",
  "version": "1.0.968",
  "name": "my-first-extension",
  "description": "Azure DevOps Extension",
  "categories": [
    "Azure Repos",
    "Azure Boards",
    "Azure Pipelines",
    "Azure Test Plans",
    "Azure Artifacts"
  ],
  "targets": [ {
    "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
  } ], 
  "icons": {
    "default": "logo.png"
  },
  "content": {
    "details": {
      "path": "overview.md"
    }
  },
  "files": [ {
    "path": "dist",
    "addressable": true
  } ]
}
```

this is my package.json file:

```json
{
  "id": "my-first-extension",
  "name": "my-first-extension", 
  "publisher": "NadavShaked",
  "version": "1.0.968",
  "description": "Azure DevOps Extension", 
  "keywords": [
    "extensions",
    "Azure DevOps",
    "Visual Studio Team Services"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist", 
    "compile": "npm run clean && npm run test && webpack --mode production", 
    "compile:dev": "npm run clean && npm run test && webpack --mode development", 
    "build": "npm run compile", 
    "build:dev": "npm run compile:dev && npm run postbuild", 
    "postbuild": "npm run package-extension -- --rev-version", 
    "package-extension": "tfx extension create --manifest-globs azure-devops-extension.json src/Samples/**/*.json", 
    "publish-extension": "tfx extension publish --manifest-globs azure-devops-extension.json src/Samples/**/*.json", 
    "test": "set TEST_REPORT_FILENAME=test-results.xml && jest --verbose"
  },
  "dependencies": { 
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.36.3", 
    "azure-devops-extension-api": "~1.157.0", 
    "azure-devops-extension-sdk": "~2.0.11", 
    "azure-devops-ui": "~2.164.0", 
    "react": "~16.13.1", 
    "react-dom": "~16.13.1" 
  }, 
  "devDependencies": { 
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.0", 
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.4.4", 
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.3", 
    "@types/react": "~16.8.2", 
    "@types/react-dom": "~16.8.0", 
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0", 
    "base64-inline-loader": "~1.1.1", 
    "css-loader": "~1.0.0", 
    "jest": "^26.1.0", 
    "jest-junit-reporter": "^1.1.0", 
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0", 
    "rimraf": "~2.6.2", 
    "sass-loader": "~10.0.5", 
    "style-loader": "~0.23.1", 
    "tfx-cli": "^0.6.3", 
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.1", 
    "ts-loader": "~5.2.2", 
    "typescript": "^3.9.6", 
    "webpack": "^5.23.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0" 
  }, 
  "jest": { 
    "transform": { 
      "^.+\\.(js|ts|tsx|jsx)$": "ts-jest" 
    }, 
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [ 
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|azure-devops-ui|azure-devops-extension-sdk)/)" 
    ], 
    "moduleNameMapper": { 
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/fileMock.js", 
      "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/styleMock.js" 
    }, 
    "preset": "ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel",
    "testResultsProcessor": "./node_modules/jest-junit-reporter", 
    "collectCoverage": true, 
    "coverageReporters": [ 
      "json", 
      "html", 
      "cobertura" 
    ], 
    "globals": { 
      "ts-jest": { 
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.test.json" 
      } 
    }
  } 
}
```

I upload the project to git my repo:
https://github.com/NadavShaked/vstsExtension/tree/master/vsts%20extension

this is the extension by run: 'vsce package'
https://easyupload.io/skwmep

this is the extension by run: 'npm run build'
https://easyupload.io/kzopux

I prefer to publish the second extension (npm run build command)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`vsce` is not the right command to publish to Azure devops.

In my `package.json`, I used `npm run publish-extension` or better `npm run package-extension` and published it by hand.